# Boolean - Optimized bool

Tags: c, gcc, cross-platform, boolean, visual-c++-6

Traditionally, C did not have a Boolean defined until C99. Thus, searching headers files to know the optimized way of creating Boolean found are:

```
Windows.h [Microsoft C++]
---------
typedef int                 BOOL;

//false
#ifndef FALSE
    #define FALSE               0
#endif

//true
#ifndef TRUE
   #define TRUE                1
#endif
```

Defined in Tipo Booleano C

```
#if (__BORLANDC__ <= 0x460) || !defined(__cplusplus)
    typedef enum { false, true } bool;
#endif
```

Provided by c-faq.com section 9

```
typedef enum {false, true} bool;
```

In objc.h the bool is defined as:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#define OBJC_BOOL_DEFINED

#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

In reply to some question on stackoverflow.com

```
typedef enum { False = 0, True = 1 } Bool;
#define bool Bool
#define true True
#define false False
```

Which one is the optimized way?

Comment: Optimised in terms of memory usage, speed, portability, ...?

Comment: @alk Yes, in every way optimized.

Comment: Why do you have two profiles? And same question from both of them?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5923069/694576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use C89, I would go with the following definitions:

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef unsigned char bool;
```

For memory reasons, `_Bool` is usually a 1-byte wide type. And in C99 `_Bool` is an unsigned type.

I personally don't like the definitions of `bool` as an enum as enum are implementation-defined types while the enum constant are always `int`.

Now if you want to favor speed over memory, you should consider using a type that matches the word size of your processor.